# Cant Delete folders Permission Denied

Tags: files, privileges

I have freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

I installed Anaconda from the shell file provided by the official links

I also installed vscode from the shell file (.sh) only provided by anaconda my home folder looks like this now

[image]

I am not able to delete these folders nor am I able to install any vscode extensions

yeah but if I run as admin then I am able to install extensions and delete folders

what shall I do

Comment: Check out linux permissions and file ownership: https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions or https://askubuntu.com/a/6727/587552  try out the command line.

Answer (score 0):

The user account that you are running as doesn't have permission to modify or delete those directories.

If you have sudo, then you're either going to have to do your things that way or edit the permissions to allow the user account itself to perform those operations.

To see what the permissions are, open a terminal, become root (if necessary), and `ls -l` on the parent directory or `ls -ld` on the directory itself.